# Snowflake pulling MaestroQA data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Has anyone here tried pulling data from MaestroQA to Snowflake?

From MaestroQA to Snowflake there is a way, but I'm wondering if there's way the other way around, from Snowflake pulling MaestroQA data, without using any APIs.

In addition, trying to look for a way to automate this.

I tried looking for documentation and any threads online, but couldn't find one.

Below are documents/links I have seen so far, but this method is from MaestroQA pushing data to Snowflake.

https://help.maestroqa.com/en/articles/1982484-data-warehouse-table-overview
https://help.maestroqa.com/en/articles/1557390-push-qa-data-to-your-data-warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake can only load data from its internal/external stages. It has no capabilities to pull data from anywhere.

You'll either need to use a tool with ETL capabilities or write your own process in, for example, python.